# Redirect to specific port

Tags: redirect, nginx, port, ubuntu-16.04

I have a server where the web server is running on 1150 port and other services on few other ports like 1151, 1152 etc. Right now user has to add port in URL to access the web server.

I want to redirect:

```
abc.example.com
abc.example.com:1150
http://abc.example.com
https://abc.example.com
http://abc.example.com:1150
```

to:

```
https://abc.example.com:1150
```

Also, I don't want to redirect other port's call (like abc.example.com:1151) to 1150. I have used following code in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl.conf` file:

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name abc.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

Its redirecting to "400 Bad Request" page. Server specification: Ubuntu 16.04, NGinx.